# AngularJS: Setting a variable and accessing it outside a $http service?

Tags: angularjs

Im having trouble with my service:

```
app.service('admin', function($http, $scope){ // Tried $scope but no dice...
    var self = this; self.admin = false;
    $http.get("api/login.php").success(function(reply){
            if(reply.realname !=null){
                self.admin = true;
            } else{ self.admin = false }
    });
    alert(self.admin); // this is just for debugging purposes. I know I havent got my service setup properly yet, I want to get it working properly first.

});
```

I want to set my services $http.get to set the self.admin to the value according to the request.

On an unrelated note:
This request checks if your an admin, which is why I can afford to do `reply.realname !=null` because it only looks for users that are admin, if theyre not it returns nothing.

Comment: You have access to it. You just have to wait until the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

As runTarm bought up, `$http` returns a promise. I took advantage of that:

```
app.service('admin', function($http){
    self.adminOrNot = function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        var promise = $http.get("api/user.php");
        return promise;
    }
});
app.controller("mainController", function($scope, admin){
    var scope = $scope;
    admin.adminOrNot().then(function(data){
        if(data.data.error != null){
            scope.adminStatus = false;
        } else if(data.data.steamid != null){
            scope.adminStatus = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Works perfectly! Coming to think of it, I probably should have put the logic in the admin service... Whatever, it works!

Then, all I had to do to retrive it in my HTML was:

```
<input type="image" src="media/admin.png" ng-hide="adminStatus">
```

I'm not exactly sure whether or not this is the best way of doing things but...

Comment: You don't need $q when you directly return the promise from $http. You're making a new promise with the defer that you aren't using.